# Docker для приложения react + nginx

Tags: docker

Создаю приложение при помощи create-react-app. Попытался настроить docker для cd.
Мой dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
CMD npm run build
EXPOSE 80
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

При запуске возникает ошибка

```
lstat build: no such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поработаю переводчиком: вы копируете директорию build, которая не существует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, вы столкнулись с двусмысленностью команды COPY. Насколько можно судить по вышестоящим командам, вы производите сборку при построении образа и пытаетесь скопировать результаты в `/usr/share/nginx/html`. Однако команда COPY предназначена для перемещения файлов и директорий из контекста внутрь строящегося образа (грубо говоря - снаружи, на хост-машине), и когда Docker пытается найти директорию build в контексте, он не может ее там обнаружить - на самом деле она находится внутри изображения, и вам нужно выполнить пару иных команд с помощью директивы RUN:

```
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html && mv build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Перед этим убедитесь, что результаты сборки действительно находятся внутри директории `build` относительно текущей рабочей директории, иначе можете столкнуться с ошибками того же характера.

Comment: Обновил пост, пишет что папки build нет, хотя команда npm run build ее создает, вопрос один, где она создается?

Comment: @Pavel я проглядел то, что `npm run build` у вас CMD, а не RUN. CMD - это команда, которая запускается при запуске контейнера, поэтому здесь у вас npm не вызывается вообще, вам нужен RUN. В то же время, в официальном изображении nginx отсутствует npm, поэтому вам придется либо его поставить (через apt-get или apk для alpine), либо собирать приложение снаружи, удалить все упоминания npm из докерфайла и добавлять директорию build через ADD или COPY из "наружного" контекста.

Comment: Я вас понял, но я так думаю что будет не правильно устанавливать nodejs в контейнер nginx? Как это делают правильно? Как сбилдить файлики в контейнере node и скопировать в контейнер nginx

Comment: @Pavel я бы прогонял `npm run build` снаружи и добавлял через ADD/COPY. Есть еще схема с двумя контейнерами (в одном билдится, в другом запускается), но она все усложняет без (обычно) реальной надобности, нативную поддержку с минимумом телодвижений обещают в следующей версии докера.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что в директории в которой вы запускаете сборку образа, есть директория/файл **build**. Команда `COPY` должна выглядеть вот так

```
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Обратите внимание на последний `/`

Comment: Слэш как раз не нужен, если раздавать дефолтным хостом официального изображения nginx, у него эта директория задана документ рутом. `docker run --rm nginx cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf | grep root`